# In Linux which folder contains installed programs, like "program files" in windows

Tags: linux, elasticsearch

I am working on a java project that is build using maven. I have to run this project on Linux. It is required to start elastic search before running the application.

I need to know the best place on Linux O.S. to keep the elastic search.

Thanks

Comment: `/usr/bin` and `/usr/local/bin`, I guess.

Comment: The ElasticSearch installer would know, so you don't have to.

Comment: I need to install elastic search before starting application from shell script

Answer (score 3):

`/usr/bin` is the standard location for programs installed by the system tooling.  `/usr/local/bin` or `/opt` might be other places to look, in case of programs installed by users without the system tooling, e.g. programs built from source locally.

For more about common conventions for paths on Unix systems, see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard

Answer (score 1):

when you enter a cmd in shell, the cmd will be found in $PATH

so check `echo $PATH`

Answer (score 0):

You can put it anywhere and add the elastic search bin directory to PATH environment variable. But maintaining different executable locations and the increasingly longer path variable would be difficult sooner or later. Hence, there are some conventions so you may choose to follow them. Here is what I would do:

Extract the elastic search package in either /usr/lib/ or /opt/
Create a softlink to the elastic search binary in /usr/lib and put the softlink in /usr/bin. PATH variable does not need to be updated.